# Вывести мультииндексы сводой таблицы в столбцы

Tags: python, pandas

Не могу вывести мультииндексы в столбцы, перепробовала разные методы, на все методы пишет одну ошибку - AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'reset_index'.

Файл с которого делала сводную таблицу: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12VsBgMFV2-9EfjZa8y0oD2MRYk6TB5ao/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106434889534507496883&rtpof=true&sd=true.

Код для создания сводной таблицы:

```
dfsun_2019pt = pd.pivot_table(dfsun_2019, values=['Балл вспышки', 'E'], 
                              index=['Дата начала вспышки', 'Активная область'], aggfunc={'Балл вспышки':'count', 'E':'sum'})
```

[image: Сводная таблица]

[image: Попытки вытащить столбцы из мультииндекса]

Comment: ну а просто `dfsun_2019pt = dfsun_2019pt.reset_index()` чем вас не устраивает? вы как-то странно применяете reset_index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать `.reset_index()` без каких-либо параметров, потому что по умолчанию этот метод убирает все уровни мультииндекса.

```
res = dfsun_2019pt.reset_index()
print(res)
print(res.info())
```

```
   Дата начала вспышки  Активная область                                                  E  Балл вспышки
0           2019-01-06              2732                                          0,0000016             1
1           2019-01-07              2732                                          0,0000016             1
2           2019-01-26              2733                                           0,000005             1
3           2019-01-27              2733                                           0,000005             1
4           2019-01-29              2733                                          0,0000019             1
5           2019-01-30              2733                         0,00000130,00000520,000002             3
6           2019-01-31              2733                         0,00000130,00000520,000002             3
7           2019-03-08              2734                                          0,0000013             1
8           2019-03-09              2734                                          0,0000013             1
9           2019-03-20              2736                                          0,0000048             1
10          2019-03-21              2736      0,00000260,00000120,00000150,00000560,0000012             5
11          2019-03-22              2736  0,00000140,0000010,00000130,00000260,00000480,...             6
12          2019-03-23              2736  0,00000140,0000010,00000130,00000260,00000480,...             6
13          2019-05-04              2740                                           0,000001             1
14          2019-05-05              2740                                          0,0000021             1
15          2019-05-06              2740  0,0000010,0000010,00000730,00000150,0000020,00...             7
16          2019-05-07              2740                                 0,00000140,0000012             2
17          2019-05-08              2740                                 0,00000140,0000012             2
18          2019-05-09              2740                                          0,0000067             1
19          2019-05-10              2740                                          0,0000067             1
20          2019-05-15              2741                                           0,000002             1
21          2019-05-16              2741                                           0,000002             1

-------------------------------------------

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 22 entries, 0 to 21
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------               --------------  ----- 
 0   Дата начала вспышки  22 non-null     object
 1   Активная область     22 non-null     int64 
 2   E                    22 non-null     object
 3   Балл вспышки         22 non-null     int64 
dtypes: int64(2), object(2)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось. Вчера именно с  .reset_index() и начинала пробовать, всё было безуспешно. Сейчас получилось.